# wordpress query categories and post from field

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have this scenario:

Categories:

23Feb2015, 24Feb2015, 25Feb2015, 26Feb2015......30Jan2099

Every day i add 5-6 posts in to a different category (today posts are in category 26Feb2015, yesterday posts was in 25Feb2015 category and so on).

On the homepage i need to make 3 different blocks where i have to query last added posts from last added category.

Example:

26Feb2015 - Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4 - Post 5 View all from 26Feb2015

25Feb2015 - Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4 - Post 5 View all from 25Feb2015

24Feb2015 - Post 1 - Post 2 - Post 3 - Post 4 - Post 5 View all from 24Feb2015

I can't figure out how to do this with custom fields, category taxonomy or...i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Here is the list of code which is useful for showing the blocks in which all the categories 5 posts display as well as display the "view all posts link " .

Note: I understand that you are using the WordPress default category .

```
$showcatPost_slug = array('testcat1','uncategorized','test2');

if(count($showcatPost_slug)>0) {
    foreach($showcatPost_slug as $slug) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page'=>5,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $slug,
                ),
            ),
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            echo '<ul>';
            while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
            endwhile;


            //for category link
            $category = get_category_by_slug($slug);
            $cateid   = $category->term_id;
            // Get the URL of this category
            $category_link = get_category_link( $cateid );

            echo "<li><a href='$category_link' title='view all links'>View all from $slug</a></li>";
            echo '</ul>';
        endif;

        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

You need to replace the slug array value to own category slug.
Below is the array which is change when you past this code into the own website.

```
$showcatPost_slug = array('testcat1','uncategorized','test2');
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not Wordpress function available to query the last added categories, and I don't think there is any date stamp info stored with the categories.

So the first thing that I thought of to solve this is below. Since you seem to be using a very specific date format, it is easy to generate the names of the last three categories using php.

```
<?php
$today = date("dMY");
$yesterday= date('dMY',strtotime("-1 days"));
$bfYesterday= date('dMY',strtotime("-2 days"));
?>
```

Then in your loop you can use get the last five posts from today, yesterday, and the day before yesterday using code like below.  (I will leave it to you to work out, the other two days and include it in your loop)

```
$getPosts = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'category_name' => $today,)
```

I see a potential problem if you miss a day, so you might want to pull a few more days, and then also use some php `if` statements to determine if the categories actually contain any posts, and if not then get the posts from the previous day.